# Does linking from an https site/page to http site triggers a security warning?

Tags: html, http, security, https, warnings

I have a secure page, with it’s full security certificate in the SSL protocol or https but when using a relative link to a non secure part of my website it forces the https protocol on it and causes all kinds of problems like the CSS styles not loading and header and footer missing. My idea is to make the link absolute, without the https. Will it trigger a security warning when clicked or will it in any way compromise the security of that page or invalidate the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a warning for a link to a non-secure part of your website. However, this isn't a good security practice. Once the user goes to a non-secure part, an attacker could use something like sslstrip to keep HTTPS turned off even when they try to go back to a secure part. Instead, you should make your entire site accessible over HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! The plan is to convert the site to a full HTTPS one and this would be a temporary solution. Notwithstanding, another question arises, can that "sslstrip" still be tried/implemented even without the link to a non secure part of my website?

Comment: The way sslstrip works, once a user is on an insecure page, sslstrip can keep them insecure even if links, forms, or other things are supposed to send them to a secure page. If they never end up on an insecure page, though, then sslstrip can't do anything.